# Flow for Automatic tasks creation for each sharepoint online members

Tags: sharepoint-online, tasks, task-list, task-assignment

I've a sharepoint group with currently 53 members. When I assign a task to all group members, it's only a single task and common for each member. I mean, once a member completes the task and clicks the complete icon, the tasks gets marked for each member and close itself.

Can I create a flow with a trigger that once I create a task with this trigger and it automatically creates same tasks  for each member of group individually?

Answer (score 1):

In case, you are using SharePoint Designer, you can use `Start a task process` to start a task process for multiple users.

[image]

And at `The Start a Task Process dialog box`, you can set `Serial` to all each user receives his/her own task

[image]

---

In case, you are using Power Automate, you can use "`Create item`" action to assgin the task to a sharepoint group successfully

[image]

> Check the details at [Assign a SharePoint task to a SharePoint group](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Assign-a-SharePoint-task-to-a-SharePoint-group/td-p/115162)

Comment: Mr. Mohamed thanks for the answer but I need more details for both options. For example, Is it possible to create an individual task on a  Planner bucket  for each member of my Teams group. That would be really make my world easier.